# Django UpdateView and ChoiceField issue. Django 1.11 python 3.6

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-1.11

I am facing a strange problem while implementing ChoiceField and UpdateView in django. I have made a small clip showing the problem that I am facing. Please watch it with subtitles/cc enabled. It will give an idea about the problem I am facing. https://youtu.be/M36TnlJvrZs. The problem goes like this.....

During `CreateView`, I set the '*gender*' `ChoiceField` as '*Female*'. But in `UpdateView` it pre-populates the '*gender*' `ChoiceField` as *Male*.

However, The `ListView` renders the '*gender*' field properly as '*Female*'.

And strangely, the **django** admin panel, displays no value at all for the '*gender*' field.

Here are all the codes:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

gender_choices = (('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female'))

class Birth(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)    
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=gender_choices)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    place_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    mother_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    address_at_time_of_birth = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    permanent_address = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    registration_no = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length = 200)    
    registration_date = models.DateField()
    issue_date = models.DateField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('birth:birth_update', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
        #return reverse('birth:birth_home')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *    

class BirthForm(forms.ModelForm):
        full_name = forms.CharField()
        gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices = gender_choices, widget=forms.Select())
        date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget = forms.DateInput(attrs = {'placeholder':'DD/MM/YYYY'}))
        place_of_birth = forms.CharField()
        mother_name = forms.CharField()
        father_name = forms.CharField()
        address_at_time_of_birth = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea())
        permanent_address = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea())
        registration_no = forms.CharField(required = False)
        registration_date = forms.DateField(required = False, widget = forms.DateInput(attrs = {'placeholder':'DD/MM/YYYY'}))
        remarks = forms.CharField(required = False)
        issue_date = forms.DateField(required = False, widget = forms.DateInput(attrs = {'placeholder':'DD/MM/YYYY'}))


        class Meta:
            model = Birth
            fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from datetime import date


class BirthHome(ListView):
    template_name = 'birth/birth_home.html'
    model = Birth
    context_object_name = 'birth_objects'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Birth.objects.all().order_by('-id')


class NewBirth(CreateView):
    model = Birth
    form_class = BirthForm
    #fields = '__all__' 
    template_name = 'birth/birth_add.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        if not obj.registration_date:
            obj.registration_date = date.today()
        if not obj.issue_date:
            obj.issue_date = date.today()
        if not (date(1900, 1, 1) <= obj.date_of_birth <= date.today()):
            form.add_error('date_of_birth', 'Please enter a valid date')
            return super(NewBirth, self).form_invalid(form)
        obj.full_name = obj.full_name.upper()
        obj.gender = obj.gender.upper()
        obj.place_of_birth = obj.place_of_birth.upper()
        obj.mother_name = obj.mother_name.upper()
        obj.father_name = obj.father_name.upper()
        obj.address_at_time_of_birth = obj.address_at_time_of_birth.upper()
        obj.permanent_address = obj.permanent_address.upper()
        if obj.remarks:
            obj.remarks = obj.remarks.upper()
        self.object = form.save()
        return super(NewBirth, self).form_valid(form)


class BirthUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Birth
    form_class = BirthForm
    template_name = 'birth/birth_update.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        if not obj.registration_date:
            obj.registration_date = date.today()
        if not obj.issue_date:
            obj.issue_date = date.today()
        if not (date(1900, 1, 1) <= obj.date_of_birth <= date.today()):
            form.add_error('date_of_birth', 'Please enter a valid date')
            return super(BirthUpdate, self).form_invalid(form)
        obj.full_name = obj.full_name.upper()
        obj.gender = obj.gender.upper()
        obj.place_of_birth = obj.place_of_birth.upper()
        obj.mother_name = obj.mother_name.upper()
        obj.father_name = obj.father_name.upper()
        obj.address_at_time_of_birth = obj.address_at_time_of_birth.upper()
        obj.permanent_address = obj.permanent_address.upper()
        if obj.remarks:
            obj.remarks = obj.remarks.upper()
        self.object = form.save()
        return super(BirthUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I searched a lot and experimented a lot as well, but to no avail. Seriously need help. Also if this approach is not correct, what should be the correct working approach??

Comment: Remove this line `obj.gender = obj.gender.upper()` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

So after lots of experimenting, I realized what the problem was!! It was in *models.py* file:

Since, I was converting all my inputs to uppercase, the *'choices'*  tuple also needed to have the values in uppercase. Initially the gender_choices tuple read like this:

```
gender_choices = (('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female'))
```

And in my views, I was making the gender as uppercase, thus causing mis-match in the declared tuple data and form data.

So, I changed the tuple to this:

```
gender_choices = (('MALE', 'MALE'), ('FEMALE', 'FEMALE'))
```

Works like a Charm!! Cheers.... And thanx for all the help and suggestions. Any feedback is always welcome :)